# How to use AngularJS to open kendo-multi-select?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a kendo-multi-select in my html. And I need use Angular to open the dropdown list. My kendo-multi-select created in angular 
`<select kendo-multi-select k-ng-model="addmember" k-options="customOptions" style="width: 100%">` And I want do the something like `addmember.open();` in AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

You can get the instance of the widget by assigning a name to the `kendo-multi-select` attribute.

```
<select kendo-multi-select="myMultiSelect" k-options="myOptions">
```

Now you can access the widget from the scope.

```
$scope.myMultiSelect.open();
```

Additional information can be found on the [KendoUI - AngularJS integration docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-references).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I dont know that I can set the model on kendo-multi-select.